# How to Read and Chage Font Size of an UILabel Dynamically?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have a problem at changing the font size in an UILabel dynamically. In my app, I have two labels.

1. The first label's size is 90*59
2. The second label's size is 59*59

Now the problem is, The first label's font size may vary during run time. I have to change the second label's font size according to the first label's font size.

I have used the following method but it doesn't works.

```
    CGFloat secondLabelsize = firstLabel.font.pointSize;
    [seconLabel setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"Exo-Light" size:secondLabelsize]];

    viewDidLod
    {
    [hr_lbl setFont: [UIFont fontWithName: @"Exo-Light" size:55]];
    }
```

Every time i have got label size as 55 only. Pls suggest me a to get current font size(first label) instead of defined font size at viewdidload.

Comment: Well , it's normal to have 55 at all times. You are getting the size of the first font and setting it as the size of the second font. Shouldn't you increase it ? I'm not sure I fully understand your question though. Please give us more details so we can come up with a better answer for you. Your code seems correct to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the answer,

label2.frame.size.width == label1.frame.size.width;

Note : if i use singe "=" its an error. If i use "==" it gives a warning but gives expected  output too. Really confused what's happening there. Any one please guide me to understand this.

Answer (score 2):

1. The @"Exo-Light" font is not able to be set to 55.
   It'a a font issue. Try using sandart @"Helvetica" to make sure the code works, then find a font closer to your exo-light (that will behave correctly, of course).
2. Also make sure the labels are properly hooked up in xib.

Comment: `The @"Exo-Light" font is not able to be set to 55. It'a a font issue` if that is true , you should be president. Nice one.

Comment: Hi George,The first label may needs to show up to 10 characters during run time. But the second label has only two characters. While showing 10 characters the font size of the first label should be reduced(i think). Now am in need to decrease the second label font size too.But i couldn't do that with this code.

Comment: Hi Teoder, I have tried with that font as per you suggestion. also gives the same result. pointSize returns only the predefined size..

Comment: Man, it's impossible, pointSize is not read-only, if you can read it, you should also set it. Check your xib file for the outlet should be hooked to the label. Or try a different font name. Otherwise, no idea.